# passing the values while loading the another form in Ext.net

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

> Hi, i am trying to dipalay one aspx page from one 
>   form (Policy.aspx). In that when i click on GridPanel ImageCommandColumn i need to loade the another form
>   Using the follwoing code.

```
<ext:Panel ID="pnlPolicies" runat="server" Height="450" Width="950" Border="false">
                <Items>
           <ext:GridPanel ID="grdPolicies" runat="server" >
                  ....
                   <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
                            <Columns>

                       <ext:Column ID="polID" runat="server" Text="ID" DataIndex="TimeOffPolicyID"/>
                                <ext:ImageCommandColumn ID="imgSettings" Width="80" Align="Center" runat="server"
                                    Resizable="false" Text="Settings">
                                    <Commands>
                                        <ext:ImageCommand Icon="BasketEdit" CommandName="Settings">
                                        </ext:ImageCommand>
                                    </Commands>
                                    <Listeners>
                                        <Command Handler="window.location = 'PolicySettings.aspx';">
                                        </Command>
                                    </Listeners>
                                </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
                               </Columns>
                        </ColumnModel>

             </items>
       </Panel>
```

> Here it is loading the "policySettings.aspx" form correctly but i want
>   to pass the GirdPanel "TimeOffPolicyID" to "policySettings.aspx" form,
>   so that i will use this id to do another processing(as like Query
>   string).
>
> Please provide the Solution to get the ID form one form GridPanle to
>   another form.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Command Handler="window.location = 'PolicySettings.aspx?ID='+record.data.TimeOffPolicyID;">
```

should work ;)